# solrj index child documents with multiple levels

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm moving from multiple cores to a single core with nested documents.(reason being matching/scoring from multiple cores is limited)
To achieve this I'm trying to index a nested structure using solrJ.

I've tested the following code but I get an error "BookDetail cannot have more than one Field with child=true"
How can I avoid this? Is this a solrj limitation?

Indexing is done as followed:
- Solr and solrj version 5.3.1

```
HttpSolrClient mytestcore=new HttpSolrClient("..."); 
mytestcore.add(dob.toSolrInputDocument(new Book());//should have some initialization
```

The structure is below(but most unused fields are removed).

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String type;
    @Field(child = true)
    private List<BookDetail> details;
    ...
}

public class BookDetail implements Serializable {

    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String type;
    @Field(child = true)
    private List<BookMetaData> bookMetaData;
    @Field(child = true)
    private List<BookContent> pages;
    ...
}

public class BookMetaData implements Serializable {

    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String type;
    ...
}

public class BookContent implements Serializable {

    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String type;
    @Field
    private String content;
    ...
}
```

**Edit**:

Currently solved it by making seperate SolrInputDocuments for each document type and add them with addChildDocument.(as seen on other answers on stackoverflow) But this solution doesn't use the annotation "child = true" anymore...

Comment: Could you add which version of solr, solrj, etc... are you using?

Comment: I'm using solrj and solr version 5.3.1

Comment: are you using spring-data-solr ?

Comment: No, should I? The class of the annotations is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

Comment: No. I just asked to understand what are you doing

Comment: Does anyobody found answer for this? Am in the same situations.
I started getting bellow error after adding "child=true" annotation.
[doc=null] missing required field: id 
Is there a better way of doing this?